# XMLHttpRequest upload onprogress - request sent finishes too fast and spends too much time at TTFB

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5.2, xmlhttprequest-level2

I have created an application to upload pictures for further processing. Everything works fine, except for the upload progress bar.

```
function upload (fData) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
            headers: { '__RequestVerificationToken': $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val() },
            data: fData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false, 
            xhr: function () {
                var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                xhr.upload.onprogress = function (evt) {
                    uploadProgress = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100;
                    $(bar).css('width', uploadProgress + '%');complete');
                };
                return xhr;
            }
        })
```

Actually, the progress calculation works fine if I use the chrome throttling functionality. After the upload finishes the server does some work and returns with the response. Everything works as desired.

[image: With throttling]

Without throttling the upload finishes instantly... at least it appears to finish instantly. I can track the upload using wireshark or simply debug the server code. The data is not there, but the *loaded* value is instantly  = the *total* value. I have the same behavior using Edge.

[image: Without throttling]

I think the same problem, but with a different setup was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310038/xmlhttprequest-upload-onprogress-instantly-complete).